# Sorting function doesn't sort, and duplicates some input

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm working on a sorting function for my Python class. Here's what I've currently got:

EDIT: I can't use any of Python's built-in sorting functions.

```
def main():

    my_list = []
    my_input = input("Input a number >>> ")
    my_list.append(float(my_input))

    while my_input != "stop":
        for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
            if float(my_input) < my_list[i]:
                my_list[i - 1] = float(my_input)
                break
        my_list.append(float(my_input))

        my_input = input("Input a number >>> ")

    print(my_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It's late here, and I've got 2 hours to turn it in. I'm exhausted and I feel like I'm missing something relatively simple.

I'm assuming that the first value the user enters isn't "stop" which will stop the function. Or should,  anyways.

Thus, I add that first value to the list, so the incoming new values have something to compare against.

With user inputs of 1, 9, 2 ,8, 3, 7, 4 this changes the output to be:

7, 8, 9, 2, 8, 3, 4, 4

There's a duplicate 4 in there, and it's not sorted.

What I was *trying* to do was to compare the user's input to the first value of the list. If it was smaller, add it to the position before that to the list. If it wasn't, move to the next value in the list and test again. If it wasn't smaller than *any* of the values in the list, just append it.

However, that didn't appear to work. Or I just did it wrong.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `my_list[i - 1]` does not prepend to the list, it replaces the value at that index.  What should happen to the value that used to be at `my_list[i - 1]` before this line was executed?

Comment: Sorry. Clarified my post a little. I don't need it to append. If it finds that the number the user entered is *less* than the one it's currently looking at in the list, then it adds that number *before* it.

Comment: You only had two lines that needed a change, see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You only had two errors in your code, note we changed the list indexing to use the .insert() function call, and added a single else onto the end of your for loop:

```
def main():
    my_list = []
    my_input = raw_input("Input a number >>> ")
    my_list.append(float(my_input))
    while my_input != "stop":
        for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
            if float(my_input) < my_list[i]:
                my_list.insert(i, float(my_input))  ### -- first change
                break
        else:                                       ### -- second change
            my_list.append(float(my_input))
        my_input = raw_input("Input a number >>> ")
    print my_list
```

Sample input using the above code:

```
Input a number >>> 4
Input a number >>> 5
Input a number >>> 6
Input a number >>> 1
Input a number >>> 2
Input a number >>> 3
Input a number >>> 4
Input a number >>> stop
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

Here is more or less the same thing broken out into two functions

```
def my_sort(a, b):
    for num in a:
        for i, val in enumerate(b[:]):
            if num > val:
                b.insert(i, num)
                break
        else:
            b.append(num)
    return b

def main():
    my_list = []
    while True:
        try:
            my_input = raw_input("Input a number >>> ")
            if "stop" == my_input:
                break
            my_input = float(my_input)
            my_list = my_sort([my_input], my_list[:])
        except ValueError:
            pass
    print my_list
```

sample input

```
>>> main()
Input a number >>> 4
Input a number >>> 5
Input a number >>> 6
Input a number >>> 1
Input a number >>> 2
Input a number >>> 3
Input a number >>> stop
[6.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is

```
while my_input != "stop":
    for i in range(0, len(my_list)):
        if float(my_input) < my_list[i]:
            my_list[i - 1] = float(my_input)
            break
    else: # no break encountered
        my_list.append(float(my_input))
```

but it seems silly to try and implement your own sort when there are many good implementations you can look up

to insert into a list at position zero(ie prepend) you can simply `my_list.insert(0,value)`

Comment: Hmm. I tried that, but that didn't seem to quite do the trick. Plus, why is the else in the same indentation as the for loop? Shouldn't it be in that of the "if" statement?

Comment: Since this is a homework assignment, I would highly suggest not using `for...else` since your teacher will most likely know that you cheated.

Comment: no the else belongs with the for ... but I second @OozeMeister's comment ... its hard to say what the problem is ... but you could implement bubble sort very easily

Comment: or go with the other answer that caught your second problem :P